# Magento 2: Add active class on selected shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, class

I want to add active class When I select a shipping method on the checkout page.

**For example**: If I select free shipping then active class should be added on radio button which is free shipping.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add below JS code in your checkout page for your requirement.

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("body").on("click", "#checkout-shipping-method-load .col-method .radio", function(){
                $("#checkout-shipping-method-load .col-method .radio").removeClass("active");
                if($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Flush the cache after the changes.

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: is there any alternative way i dont want to use jquery

Comment: There is no other way to do this @Ronak, else you need to write this JS in your Knockout.js file

Comment: Selected active class is not removed if I changed shipping method in this code.

Comment: nope. still active class is not removed if changed shipping method

Comment: Now give a try with updated code.

Comment: Thanks it worked